# Selenium cssselector shows correct webelement but script always run exception no such element

Tags: selenium, exception, element, service-locator

I got stuck not just for this one case. Many cases came out with nosuchelement exception, I cannot find the reason why. I use chrome console to locate the element and it shows correct result. Is that possible something wrong with the page itself, not my script?

[image]
[image]

---

Comment: have tried with any other locators?

Answer (score 0):

Context click on the element you are trying to click, and see if the element is inside any frame. Try to navigate through the tags and see if this element is under any iframe.

switch to the iframe using,
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("iframexpath")));